# iOS left side menu using MFSideMenu

Tags: ios, iphone, menu

Using the [MFSideMenu for iOS](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu) I noticed a strange behaviour when running the app on a larger display (iPhone 6 Plus). On **left side**'s bottom I get a padding, meaning that somehow the height does not fit the screen coordinates.

Does someone had this problem? If yes, did you found a solution for it?

Comment: use [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) as its best than MFSideMenu

Comment: @Prince thanks for the suggestion. I agree it's better.